# ¿Cuál es el origen de la frase "a ciencia cierta"?

Tags: historia, locuciones

El significado de la expresión es claro, y el DLE lo explica:

> [**a**, o **de, ciencia cierta**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9AwuYaT)
>
> 1. locs. advs. Con toda seguridad, sin duda alguna. *Saber a ciencia cierta.*

Supongo que la frase es lo suficientemente intuitiva como para que alguien no nativo adivine su significado, pero no deja de parecerme curioso por qué y cuándo empezó a usarse esa frase fija.

¿Se conoce el origen de esta expresión?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pues vamos a ver, porque cuando veo que una expresión aparece en el diccionario de Covarrubias de 1611 me echo a temblar:

> Saber de cierta ciencia manera de hablar para certificar vno lo que sabe.

Si una expresión aparece en este diccionario, es difícil averiguar su origen. Y más si vemos en el CORDE casos de esta expresión ¡en el siglo XIV! Al parecer se usaba en documentos notariales, con textos como los siguientes (negritas mías):

> *Seppan quoantos esta present carta veran et oyran, que yo Diago Diaz, fijo de don Johan Diaz ceillero, et yo Eluira Periz su muger, vezinos d'Esteilla, non seyendo forçados ni falagados ni apremiados nin de ningun mal ingeynamiento engeynados, mas **de nuestra cierta ciencia**, con bonos, liures et francos coraçones et agradables volutades...* (1378)
>
> *Sepan todos quantos aquesta present carta pública verán que yo Garcí Ferrández de Sayas, racionero en la iglesia de Santa María la Mayor de la ciudat de Calatayut, **de mi cierta ciencia** e de mis derechos bien certificado por mí e por todos los míos presentes e advenideros...* (1381)
>
> *Sea conocida cosa a todos homes cómo yo Pere Savrín, vezino de Ruvihuelos, aldea de la ciudat de Teruel, **de mi cierta ciencia**, por mí e los míos presentes e advenidores, sin retenimiento alguno, a honor e reverencia de la pasión de Nuestro Señor Jesucristo e de la Virgen Santa María, su madre, e de toda la cort celestial...* (1384)

Entiéndase que por entonces se entendía "ciencia" como "el conocimiento cierto de alguna cosa por su causa". Lo que hace de "cierta ciencia" una expresión redundante, pero que desde sus orígenes ya implicaba la idea de "doy fe de que esto es así", de algo era así "con seguridad".

Y veo incluso que podemos irnos más atrás buscando una variación de la palabra:

> *E a esto nos era contrario don Johan diçiendo que el sabia que vos assi lo entendiades que los dos pudiessen decir que en otra manera no seria natura de compromes que avenir podria que nunqua se avernirian los tres e nos diçiendo que antes sabiamos nos que **de cierta sciencia** e por bien de los feytos lo aviades assi puesto e que assi parecia por el escripto que vos aviades enviado con el Comendador e el Arcidiagno.* (1304)

Y más atrás:

> *... uinieron de manifiesto e reconoscen **de cierta e uerdadera sciencia** sabudament e certificados de todo en todo que los dichos monesterios de Sant Pedro e de Sant Miguel...* (1285)

Y ya por fin damos con un texto de 1250 que contiene la expresión en latín vulgar, el cual tiene una estructura similar a los documentos notariales vistos más arriba:

> *Noverint universi quod nos Iacobus per nos et omnes nostros successores indulgemus, concedimus et **ex certa sciencia** constituimus in perpetuum quod nunquam in villa de Aliazira vel eius termino a mercibus sive quibuslibet aliis rebus accipiatur amplius quam inferius est statutum, videlicet.*

Todo esto nos hace llegar al papado de [Inocencio III](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inocencio_III) (Papa desde 1198 hasta 1216), en el que al parecer se creó la fórmula "confirmatio ex certa scientia", consistente en una corroboración de los hechos con pleno conocimiento de los mismos. Su primer uso fue en textos eclesiásticos para que constara que el Papa había tenido pleno conocimiento de lo acontecido, y lo corrobora. Más información en [esta tesis doctoral](http://studylib.es/doc/5495492/ex-certa-scientia) de Valentín Gómez-Iglesias, que menciona a Inocencio III como usuario de la fórmula. Ciertamente, el primer caso en el CORDE de *ex certa scientia* data de 1225, lo que no quita para que haya otros casos previos no documentos en este corpus, correspondientes a este papado.

Con todo esto, ahora podemos recorrer este mismo camino a la inversa, para darnos cuenta de cómo una fórmula usada por el Papa para dar fe de algo pasó a ser usada también por otros cargos de la Iglesia, por nobles y finalmente por cualquier persona que quisiera dejar constancia de que tenía pleno conocimiento de algo.

Comment: Aunque por lo visto al principio se usaba al revés: *cierta ciencia*, que suena más como un tipo de ciencia sin especificar.

Comment: @blonfu aunque eso es lo que parece, en este caso la palabra "cierta" se usaba igual que como usamos nosotros ahora "ciencia cierta". Fíjate si no en el texto que dice "de cierta e verdadera sciencia".

Comment: Sí, había puesto en el comentario *hoy sonaría como* pero luego lo he cambiado porque no estaba seguro si antes también se usaba de esa forma o no